# Is there a high-level language that can be compiled to shell and provides protection against the many hazards encountered in shell programming?

Tags: shell

I've been told that Coffeescript and TypeScript can be used to write code that can be compiled into Javascript. They also provide some protection against the many eccentricities of JS and additional abstraction to improve productivity. Has anyone tried something like this for Shell? Is there some middle ground between writing in Shell and writing in Python, but without losing performance?  Please don't hate me :)

Comment: The shell is mainly a DSL for executing programs. It doesn't get much higher level than that, at least on a single system.

Comment: The point of compiling to shell would be portability, not performance.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong terms. I want to be able to write shell scripts in a language/library/framework which has more predictable behaviour. For instance, iterating over the files in a directory requires one to overwrite the IFS variable (and maybe other defaults as well). I want a way so that I am able to generate shell scripts but I have workflows for common tasks (explicit functions or implicit idioms) that are safer.

Comment: @ApoorvGupta have a look at [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to use python to drive the binaries (including pipes and redirection), that you would otherwise call from bash. There is not need to translate such a script in bash, the speed gain would be minimal if existing at all.

Comment: xon.sh, plumbum and https://github.com/tdenniston/bish look like they could let me get away from all the stupid-isms (see wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php) of bash.

Answer (score 1):

There's Joey Hess' shell-monad for Haskell ([blog post](https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/shell_monad/), [hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shell-monad)) that can be used to write code in Haskell that will generate a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the Haskell suggestion but with Turtle instead. It allows code that looks just like a shell script but is safely typed.